# Prove linear map property

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to work out a proof for the exercise below, but I'm really stuck. In fact, I'm not sure if I entirely understood what the exercise asks. Why does it want us to show that the linear map will go from $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$?

Prove that if $A \in M_{m \times n}$ is a matrix which rows are $\vec{a}_{j} \in \mathbb{R}^n$
and $f(\vec{x}) = A\vec{x}$, then $f: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f_{j}(\vec{x})=\vec{a}_{j}\cdot\vec{x}$

Also prove that if $A \in M_{m \times n}$ is a matrix which columns are $\vec{b}_{j} \in \mathbb{R}^n$
and $f(\vec{x}) = \vec{x}A$, then $g: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f_{j}(\vec{x})=\vec{b}_{j}\cdot\vec{x}$

Comment: I would  us proof by induction on n.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct wording? It seems like $f$ should go from $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R^m}$ and the second part doesn't makes sense at all because you cannot multiply $\vec{b}_{j}$ by $A$ since $n$ and $m$ can be different.

Comment: Well, this exercise was written in Portuguese by a Spanish-native teacher. As for my English translation, it is accurate. My colleagues and I also wondered if there is anything wrong with the exercise wording. It really does not make much sense to show that it only applies to f: R^2 -> R^2. And you definitely found a mistake made by the teacher on the second part. I will talk to him. Thanks for your help.